# CSS Layout issue (1 button either side of image)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 2 issues:
First is why does this HTML render differently in IE and Chrome
Secondly, how do I align the 2 buttons so they are the same height as the image and flush next to it on either side.

http://jsfiddle.net/ur23z7f0/3/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" value "1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_8LIsmeu9Fzs/SdadTd-wVDI/AAAAAAAAALA/9Pt_3nCrsz0/s400/BURGER.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" value "2"/>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.image-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 5px;
}
.button-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 5px;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
}
input {
    height: 200px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` you should take care on vertical alignment.
Total size of an element is its width / height plus padding plus border plus margin, so to fit the content your wrapper's height should 210px.

The below code is fixed and so works the same on the different browsers:

```css
.wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 210px;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.image-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;   
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 5px;
}
.button-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 5px;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
}
input {
    height: 200px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" value "1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_8LIsmeu9Fzs/SdadTd-wVDI/AAAAAAAAALA/9Pt_3nCrsz0/s400/BURGER.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" value "2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```